# How can I make a callback function in the lodash forEach populate an array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following code:

```
$scope.option.cityMap = data.reduce(function (rv, v) {
                       rv[v.cityId] = v;
                       return rv;
                   }, {});
```

Can someone tell me how I can implement this with the _.lodash forEach ? I have looked at the docs but I am not sure how to implement the callback function so it creates an array.

```
$scope.option.cityMap = _.forEach(data,
```

Comment: I am reading that the _.reduce is not so efficient. That's why I was hoping for a way to implement this with the forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the functional helpers all solutions are less efficient than "imperative style":

```
var cityMap = {};
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  cityMap[data[i].cityId] = data[i];
}
// return cityMap;
```

If performance is really an issue, make a function from above. It's pure and functional, if looked from outside (data in, data out, no side-effects).

You can also use [`_.zipObject`](http://lodash.com/docs#zipObject):

```
var cityMap = _(data).map(data, function (v) {
  return [v.cityId, v];
}).zipObject().value();
```

or [`reduce`](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce), as we are not copying the accumulator `rv` (cheating in a sense), it should be quite efficient as well.

```
var cityMap = _.reduce(data, function (rv, v) {
  rv[v.cityId] = v;
  return rv;
}, {});
```